# Is Bhagavan Krishna's sister a Nityasuri?

Tags: krishna, vaishnavism, sri-vaishnava, vishishtadvaita

Many of us are familiar with the story of Bhagavan Krishna's birth. Specifically, when Kamsa finally arrives to kill the eighth child of Vasudeva and Devaki, the child who has taken Krishna's place, in ethereal voice, proclaims the safe arrival of Bhagavan Vishnu as Krishna avatara on Earth and announces the doom that is to befall Kamsa and then disappears.  Puranas attest that this child is none other than incarnate of Vishnu's YogamAyA.

***According to SriVaishnavam***, Is YogamAyA identified as a Nityasuri? If not, what is the relation to Bhagavan Vishnu? Sometimes, YogamAyA is also referred to as VishnuDurga, what is the reason behind this?

Note: Nityasuris are the attendants of srimannArAyaNa. They are jivAtmas like any other mukta in Paramapadam except that they have been in Moksha eternally. Some famous examples include srimannArAyaNa's weapons like ChakrathAzhwar & ShankAzhwar, his general Viswaksenar or SenaiMudaliar and his eternal serpent couch SheshAzhwar.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Concept of Nityasuri is unique to VisistAdvaita & SriVaishnavam, hence I did not feel the need to explicate it. Now, having said that, I disagree that there is anything well-defined called a general perspective, perhaps you are referring to Shakta perspective.

Comment: @TheDestroyer In the body, I have already mentioned that i'm looking in accordance with SriVaishnavam in bold-italic.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar Thanks for the related link - the overlap seems to be in so far as establishing identity of Krishna's sister is concerned(which puranas state is YogamAyA). I am asking for different clarifications given this as fact, namely, relation of YogamAyA to Vishnu as per SriVaishnavam, etc,.

Comment: I remember this quote from Bhagavan Krishna himself  "My sister took birth and saved my life". I am not familiar with Sri Vaishnava definition but this does not sound like the work of a jivatma.

Comment: @moonstar2001 Interesting! can you share where you came across this quote?

Comment: In Srimad Bhagavatam when Akrura has a vision of Vaikuntha, he sees among the attendants of Vishnu, Yogamaya Devi as well, who is called as his own Maya. Does this qualify as a definition of Nityasuri?

Comment: @Surya It seems so! Does it say anything else there about the denizens of Vaikuntha? If not, this might very well be the case. I would think that all the denizens of Vaikuntha are attendants of Vishnu so telling Nityasuris apart just from this isn't conclusive unless you have the specific verses we can examine.

Comment: @LakshmiNarayanan The other people listed are Mahalakshmi, in her eight forms, Shiva, Brahma, Garuda, Vishvaksena and the other attendants, Prahlada and the Vedas.

Comment: @Surya Can you share the link to the section? Thanks!

Comment: @Surya et al. Does that make Mahalakshmi a nityasuri as well? Is she a mere jivatma? Mere presence in court cannot be the deciding criterion for concluding whether someone is a jivatma nityasuri.

Comment: @moonstar2001 Agreed, which is why i'm interested in reading the section to see if there are further clues :)